# Error while Installing Pillow / PyAutoGUI on Windows 10

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

i wanted to install PyAutoGUI via pip.

It worked, until it installed Pillow.

Here is the error:

> Command "c:\users\erazor\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Erazor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ff50gy2x\Pillow\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Erazor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hfqa44g5\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Erazor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ff50gy2x\Pillow\

[Here is a Hastebin forme the command promt.](https://hastebin.com/yagokohici.sql)

I hope you can help me.

EDIT: I tried han solos comment. It did not Work its the Same error but now i get

> Failed building wheel for Pillow

as an additional error.

EDIT: New error:

> Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow
>     Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py) ... error
>     Failed building wheel for Pillow
>     Running setup.py clean for Pillow
>   Failed to build Pillow
>   Installing collected packages: Pillow, pyscreeze, pyautogui
>     Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
>   Command "c:\users\erazor\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Erazor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m5b1ubtx\Pillow\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Erazor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ot3l1c72\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Erazor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m5b1ubtx\Pillow\

Comment: Try a `pip install -U setuptools wheel` and see if it resolves

Comment: @hansolo It didn't work. I now get Failed building wheel for Pillow as an additional Error.

Comment: Use python 3.7 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pillow's latest supported Python version is 3.7, not 3.8.